# Include header in index?

Tags: php, html, indexing, header

I have a small problem i have the following code and want to add a language switch to my site.
Let's assume I have a header.php and an index.php. 
I want to include the buttons and the script in the header.php. The Header.php is included in the index.php. How can I access the functions in the header from index.php ?

My Code :

In the Header.php

```
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body.fr > p[lang=en] {
        display: none;
      }
      body.en > p[lang=fr] {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
    <button onclick="document.body.className='en'">English</button>
    <button onclick="document.body.className='fr'">French</button>
```

In the Index.php

```
                <?php
                include('header.php');
                ?>  

  <body class="en">
    <p lang="en">This is English</p>
    <p lang="fr">This is French</p>
  </body>
```

If i click on the buttons, the text don't change. I assume that i must integrate the header.php with the index.php content but how ?

Comment: Hi :) Why do you have the buttons in the _header.php_? And why they out of the `body`?

Comment: Why do you have the buttons in both the **header.php** and the **index.php** files?

Comment: @MoshFeu Because i dont like to import the Buttons on every page. I have a lot of pages. Like hello.php and world.php and i would like to have the buttons in the header that are included in all files.

Comment: @OmariCelestine Sorry my mistake

Comment: @M.Antony The buttons should be in the body and the css, if inline, should be placed aas the last content in the body.

Comment: @OmariCelestine But than i must add the buttons to every page manually right ?

Comment: @M.Antony You could have a PHP file with the buttons that you will include on each of the pages same as with the **header.php** file. I will post a suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you have the buttons in both the **header.php** and the **index.php** files but removing the `>` from the CSS seems to solve the problem. Also I would suggest you format your code similar to the following:

**header.php**

```
<head>
    <title>Languages</titke>
    <!-- Meta tags CSS and JavaScript Files -->
</head>
```

**language_buttons.php**

```
<button onclick="document.body.className='en'">English</button>
<button onclick="document.body.className='fr'">French</button>
```

**footer.php**

```
<style type="text/css">
    body.fr p[lang=en] {
        display: none;
    }
    body.en p[lang=fr] {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <?php include('header.php'); ?>  

    <body class="en">
        <?php include 'language_buttons.php'; ?>

        <p lang="en">This is English</p>
        <p lang="fr">This is French</p>

        <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```